# Pattern: Similar behavior who can be different

Tags: design-patterns

I have to create a design for a set of class who will create document in different kind of format: PDF, Word, text.

All this kind of file will have a similar structure: header, title, main, footer. Internal structure can be different for the same kind of file.

```
IPage
  createTitle();
  CreateHeader();
  createMain();
  createFooter();

AbstractPdfIPage implement IPage

PdfReport extend AbstractPdfIPage

IDocumentGeneration
  generateDocument();


WordGeneration implement IDocumentGeneration
  generateDocument(IPage page);

PdfGeneration implement IDocumentGeneration
  generateDocument(IPage page);
```

In generateDocument I could have something like

```
if( page!=null){
    page.createTile();
    page.createHeader();
    ...
}
```

So i can have different implementation of createTitle, createHeader, createMain, createFooter

Are there any pattern to doing this kind of behavior?

**edit:**
because i would like to have possibility to reuse these methods,

createTitle();
  createHeader();
  createMain();
  createFooter();

i think they have two possibility, create an interface for every of theses method and create a class and get something like

generateDocument(ICreateTitle ict, ICreateHeader ich...)

or using class who extends a abstract class who implement some method

AbstractPdfIPage implement IPage

AbstractPdfIPage will implement all of theses method.
So i will have possibility to reuse or reimplement any of these method

don't know witch one is the best and if there is a better one

Answer (score 2):

You've just described the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), which is a specialization of the [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

However, since [Design Patterns](http://amzn.to/XBYukB) itself recommends that we should **favour Composition over Inheritance** (a statement with which, based on my experience, I completely agree), you should consider using the same overall approach with a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) instead of a Template Method.

Comment: I dont' know if i could use Strategy pattern. The behaviour of createTitle, createHeader, createMain, createFooter method can be different and in strategy example i saw, like on wikipedia (execute example), only one method is redefined. Me i would like to use the same method generateDocument, but this one have some other who can be redefined. Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: You could define a Strategy interface that defines `createTitle`, `createHeader`, `createMain`, and `createFooter` methods, or you could define four different Strategy interfaces that each define one of these methods.

Comment: Possibly... That's a bit difficult to tell from the code you've supplied. Pure use of strategy doesn't require inheritance, so I don't think the `AbstractPdfIPage` fits anywhere in the Strategy pattern, but then again, I also can't really see what it does.

Comment: But why is it abstract?

Comment: to define attribute, method then child class can reuse

Comment: createTitle and other will have a specific paramter for pdf who will not be the same then for excel one... and the second parameter will be the same for the both. createTitle(T t,DataInfo di). For pdf T will be Document (itext) and for excel T will be Workbook (apache poi). I don't know if it's possible to do something clean will all theses constraint